# how to count img alt tag having no value and no alt tag img tag with regex

Tags: asp.net, regex

getting compilation error,saying **Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement and ; Expected.**  how to count `img` tags having no `alt` attributes as well as `img` tags with an `alt` attribute containing an empty string.

Both `img` tags below should be counted, but only the second one is counted in my code:

```
<img src="http://google.com/images/38524_1105/16/geolocate.png" class="absmiddle" alt="" />

<img src="http://google.com/images/38524_1105/16/geolocate.png" class="absmiddle" />
```

Here's my code (my `aspx.cs` file):

```
 MatchCollection ImgAltTag = Regex.Matches(strIn, "<img[^>]*alt=['"].+['"]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: You cannot use regular expressions to parse HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/969494

Comment: What if the image name contains `alt` word?

Answer (score 0):

If `jQuery` is an option:

```js
var count = $('img').filter(function(){
  return !$(this).attr('alt'); // false when contains alt attribute
}).length;

document.write(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="alt.png" class="absmiddle" alt="" />
<img src="alt.png" class="absmiddle" />
```

---

But, asking your question, here is your regex:

```
<img[^>]*alt=['"].+['"]
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/qV6hS9/1)

---

Hope one of them could help.

Comment: im getting error while using in c#]

Comment: getting error . while using with c#.Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement and ; Expected.